# Get INI file value with WiX

Tags: wix, wix3, ini

I'd like to read a value from an INI file in a WiX installer. I've just tried to use IniFileSearch, but this looks for an INI file or a path specified in an INI file (the documentation isn't clear), it doesn't *read a value* from an INI file.

Do I need a customaction to do this? And if so, what would people suggest? Seems very strange if WiX doesn't have this, though!

Code I'm using:

```
<Property Id="SP">
    <IniFileSearch Id="SearchSPVersion" Name="sp.ini" Section="ServicePack"
    Key="Version" Type="raw">
        <DirectorySearch Id="SPIniFilePath" Path="[CFGPATH]">
            <FileSearch Id="SPIniFile" Name="sp.ini"/>
        </DirectorySearch>
    </IniFileSearch>
</Property>
```

INI file:

```
[ServicePack] 
Version=1
```

I've tried with and without the directory and file search (using full path in 'name'), and I've tried type = "raw", "file" and "directory".

Comment: Is this value used anywhere other than the install?

Comment: Yes. In a condition. Otherwise I wouldn't need to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in a DTF custom action:
[INI File Reader in C#](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/05/ini-file-reader-in-c.html)

Comment: Mentioned path is not available. What is the solution for this question? Can you please give the solution to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70243157/change-the-rootdrive-in-xml-with-the-path-specified-in-ini-file

Answer (score 4):

The [Windows Installer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369283(VS.85).aspx) states that the .ini file must be present in the default Microsoft Windows directory.

It's a bit confusing as FileSearch and DirectorySearch are valid WiX children, however I believe this is for searching for a file or directory specified *within* the INI file itself. You'll notice the three types of values you can search for within an INI file are directory, file and raw.

It's a limitation of Windows Installer, not of WiX. The Microsoft interfaces for reading INI files (e.g. [GetPrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353(VS.85).aspx)) looks in the Windows folder if a path is not specified. I guess the Windows Installer team decided not to simplify things and only support INI files in the Windows folder by not allowing a dynamic path.

Comment: Right. That's sucky, isn't it?

Comment: Well, only if you're still using INI files. Shouldn't you be using the registry these days?

Comment: a) It's only in an INI file, if it was in the registry I'd be fine.
b) On a tangent: I'm not sure whether Microsoft is planning to ditch the registry ever, but as a concept I personally don't like it... But that's not really important.

Comment: "It's a limitation of Windows Installer, not of WIX."  In researching this question I've seen this statement multiple times.  It would be more correct to state that it is a limitation of the Windows installer and of WIX.  It isn't like WIX is forced to not extend where the Windows Installer falls down.

Comment: @MichaelHunter that has to be the best comment I've read! It shares my sentiments toward that statement.

Comment: @saschabeaumont And how well does the Windows registry work for network installations?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but I was hoping to save someone from the same pain I went through....

This does read a *value* from an ini file, at least so far as my tests with Wix3.5 and 3.6 beta. i.e.

```
<Property Id="MY_PROPERTY">
        <IniFileSearch Id="myIniSearch" Name="myConfigFile.ini" Section="section1" Key="name" Type="raw" />
    </Property>

    <Condition Message="myconfigfile not def.">MY_PROPERTY</Condition>
```

With the corresponding ini file saved in C:\windows\myConfigFile.ini (Windows 7) :

```
[section1]
name=testing
```

However, I burned many hours trying to figure out why this appeared to not work before realising that the ini file must be **ANSI** and not UTF8! An ANSI encoded .ini file in the correct location i.e. c:\Windows\some.ini will work.

UTF8 files are just not read, no error occurs, the property assignment just doesn't happen.

Comment: Looking at your example it seems that you agree with @saschabeaumont that the INI file must be stored in the Windows directory. So bascially Windows forces developers to clutter the Windows directory with their INI files? Oh well....