# WIX: Override IniFileSearch while installing if MSI has command line params

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In my WIX setup project, I am reading some properties from an INI file.

Is there a way to override the IniFileSearch during installation if any of the Property values are passed as command line params. (I am trying to do this so that it works with silent installations as well.)

Code Snippet:

```
<Property Id="WEBDIR" >
   <IniFileSearch Id="WebsitesDirIni" Name="Setup.ini" Section="InstallLocations" Key="WebsitesDir" Type="raw"/>
</Property>
```

What I'd like is that if I were to execute the msi as shown below, it accepts the value given by the command line param rather than looking up a value in the ini file.

```
msiexec /i install.msi WEBDIR=C:\MyOverriddenPath
```

Answer (score 1):

INI file searches can search only in the Windows directory. So for your scenario you can try using the custom action mentioned in this thread:
[Get INI file value with WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193091/get-ini-file-value-with-wix)

This way you can simply condition the custom action with the property you set from command line.

Answer (score 1):

Your example will set WEBDIR to the command line value which is then **replaced** by the ini file value.

You can achieve the result you want by using a *different command line property name* and setting WEBDIR to that value if defined. i.e.

```
    <SetProperty Id="WEBDIR" After="AppSearch" Value="[DIR]">
        DIR
    </SetProperty>
```

Note that this is supplimental to your existing code. You could then call :

```
msiexec /i install.msi DIR=C:\MyOverriddenPath
```

Which would override the WEBDIR property defined in the ini file.