# How to read the content of an INI file not placed in the WindowsFolde with WiX?

Tags: wix, ini

I'm currently using WiX in order to create an MSI which reads custom parameters set by the user in a *.ini* file, placed in the *TempFolder*.

However, it seems that WiX is only able to read *.ini* from the *WindowsFolder*, but the users can't write in it, so I stumble into this issue: either WiX cannot read the changes, or either the user cannot make the changes (of course copying the edited *.ini* into the WindowsFolder doesn't work either since WiX cannot read it in first case).

While searching I found this *[Get INI file value with WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193091/get-ini-file-value-with-wix)* but unfortunately I have absolutely no idea how to use or what are custom actions, and i'm having a hard time finding a begginer's guide for it.

Is there another bypass or can you please provide an easy step by step tutorial in order to read *.ini* values from anywhere ?

Thanks in advance, I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Please understand that an MSI is a Windows Installer package (aka program database). It is Windows Installer the does the actions, either standard or custom. Would setting properties on the [msiexec command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/command-line-options) serve your purposes?

Comment: I did it initially but was not really viable for who i'm working with. Thankfully I just solved my issue by creating a simple VBS script which is called by a custom action and doesn't require the use of visual studio or dll.